# Getting Around Webdriver's Lack of Interactions API in Safari

Tags: python, safari, selenium-webdriver

I am needing to use the ENTER key in Safari. Turns out Webdriver does not have the Interactions API in the Safari driver. I saw some code from a question about this with a java solution using Robot, and was wondering if there is a purely Python way to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

Darth,

Mac osascript has libraries for Python. Be sure to 'import os' to gain access to the Mac osascript functionality.

Here is the command that I am using:

`cmd = """
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke return' 
"""
        os.system(cmd)`

This does a brute force return. If you're trying to interact with system resources such as a Finder dialog, or something like that, make sure you give it time to appear and go away once you interact with it. You *can* find out what windows are active (as well as setting Safari or other browsers 'active', if it hasn't come back to front) using Webdriver / Python.

Another thing that I have to do is to use a return call after clicking on buttons within Safari. Clicks are a little busted, so I will click on something to select it (Webdriver gets that far), then do an osascript 'return' to commit the click.

I hope this helps.

Best wishes,

-Vek

***If this answer appears on ANY other site than stackoverflow.com, it is without my authorization and should be reported***